# Review scraping loop with Selenium and Python repeats the first entry instead of moving to next ones

Tags: python, selenium, review

I am currently trying to automatically get reviews from Tripadvisor (https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g186338-d553603-Reviews-London_Eye-London_England.html) and save them to a csv using Selenium and Python. I have come across this code, which works well for restaurants and hotels, but not "Things to do": https://bitbucket.org/devlobeslab/com.lobeslab.webseries.python/src/master/scraping/code/scraper.py

I've adapted most of the code and managed to store first data entries in the csv and move on to the next page. However, for each page, the first entry is repeated 10 times in the csv and then the program moves onto the next page instead of going through the 10 different reviews. If anybody has an idea where the problem lies, that'd be super helpful!

Website Elements:

```
NEXT_BTN = (By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='Next page']")
REVIEW_LIST = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_1c8_1ITO']")
REVIEWS = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_1c8_1ITO']/div")
SCORE = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_1c8_1ITO']/div[1]/span/span/div[3]/*[local-name()='svg' and @class='zWXXYhVR' and contains(@title, 'bubbles')]")
DATE = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_3JxPDYSx']")
TITLE = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='DrjyGw-P _1SRa-qNz _19gl_zL- _1z-B2F-n _2AAjjcx8']/span[1]")
REVIEW_TEXT = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='DrjyGw-P _26S7gyB4 _2nPM5Opx']/span[@class='_2tsgCuqy']")

def find_element(find_from, element):
return find_from.find_element(element[0], element[1])
```

I also tried to write ".//div... for SCORE, DATE, TITLE and REVIEW_TEXT, as this was suggested in answers to similar questions, but this unfortunately results in a "NoSuchElementException".

Loop:

```
# Load and get all reviews
    time.sleep(3)
    review_list = find_element(driver, REVIEW_LIST)
    reviews = find_elements(review_list, REVIEWS)
    print("[INFO]", len(reviews), "reviews found")

    for review in reviews:
        # Read the interesting review information
        score_span = find_element(review, SCORE)
        score = score_span.get_attribute("title")
        date = find_element(review, DATE).text
        title = find_element(review, TITLE).text
        text = find_element(review, REVIEW_TEXT).text.replace("\n", "")
        # Save to CSV
        csvWriter.writerow((score, date, title, text,))

    print("[INFO] Page ready")
    if curr_page == pages:
        break
    else:
        next_page = find_element(driver, NEXT_BTN)
        driver.get(next_page.get_attribute("href"))
        curr_page += 1
```

HTML of the website:
[Screenshot of the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkeIr.png)

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show us your methods like `find_element`? And if possible a link to that web page

Comment: they're not relative (to the review) so you'll fetch the first ones every time

Comment: @DMart This can be more than relative to this problem

Comment: @Prophet: Added the find_element method. Methods are the same ones used in the bitbuckt example code.

Comment: @DMart: How do I put them relative to the review? I tried writing ".//..." and in the "..." using the XPATH relative to the overarching "div" review element, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as has been mentioned is that your code is not dynamic.

The xpath you are using for "REVIEWS" is fixed to the first entry. My suggestion is for you to iterate over that xpath. e.g. in the webpage you shared the first entry has this xpath

`//*[@id="tab-data-qa-reviews-0"]/div/div[5]/div[1]`

and the second one has this xpath

`//*[@id="tab-data-qa-reviews-0"]/div/div[5]/div[2]`

Give the above, we can infere that you need to modify the value in the last bracket to iterate over the comments the way you want to.